# Invalid search query in NetSuite

Tags: python, rest, netsuite

Im trying to query a transaction_lines from NetSuite but I keep going to get the `bad request` error.

```
 'title': 'Bad Request',
 'status': 400,
 'o:errorDetails': [{'detail': 'Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Invalid search type: transaction_lines.',
   'o:errorQueryParam': 'q',
   'o:errorCode': 'INVALID_PARAMETER'}]}
```

Comment: you'd have a better likelihood of getting help if you show the query too.

Comment: I managed and did for `transaction_line`. The table name for the REST api is `transactionline` not `transaction_lines`.  I follow this url now https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/analytics/record/transactionLine.html  to pick the right names but still some of them does not work. Fore example: Entity, Accounts